# Jquery Drag list item from nested list on others list items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have the following structure:

```
<ul id="trylist">
    <li id="1">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li id="sub1">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <ul>
                    <li id="subsub1">...</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="sub2">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <ul>
                    <li id="subsub2">...</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

I'm using JqueryUI.

I would like to drag a "sub" or "subsub" list item, without dragging the entire nested tree under it, over any parent list item.

The drag event is triggered by a button whose id is "menuButtonMoveFolder" and starts when I click on an item in the list so i have something like:

```
$('body').delegate('div#menuButtonMoveFolder','click',function(event)
{
    $('ul#trylist li').draggable({
        revert: true, 
        // helper: "clone" How should i set it?
        start: function() {
            //
        },
        drag: function() {
            //
        },
        stop: function() {
            //
        }
    });
});
```

I've to drop the list item i'm dragging over any of the list items above it, anyway, if i click over a list items i get the item and the all nested items inside of it. How can i only drag away one and only one item from the list including its html code and id/class?

Sorry for my bad english, i could've made some errors in this code because i wrote it live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if i've understand you right, but when it comes to Drag & Drop sorting of nested lists, i've always used a jQueryUI extension from Manuele J Sarfatti. It extends the standard jQueryUI.sortable() function and enables you to sort list items in or out of their parents by just dragging left or right.

You can try it here:
http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable

Comment: It could be a good extension to do what i need, but, can i obtain the id of the item i'm dragging and id of the item where i drop it? I need only these 2 values, not the entire tree..

Comment: Sure, you could get all informations about any event while dragging, for example when starting a drag operation:

`$("ul").nestedSortable({
  start: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.item); // < ui.item represents the item that is being dragged
  }
});`